# Is there a SQL Server system view I can query to get the expression for a view column?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a system view that contains the expressions for view columns?

If I have a view:

```
create view myview as
  select ...
     , pay
     , pay * 1.5 as overtime_pay
  from another_view
```

I would like to be able to do something like

```
select expression_view 
   from ?
   where column = 'overtime_pay'
```

and have "pay * 1.5" returned

Comment: I don't think this is stored anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of such a built in view, but you could do something like this_

```
create view myview as
  select 'test' as testColumn
     , object_id
     , object_id * 1.5 as overtime_pay
  from sys.objects
  GO


declare @viewname varchar(100)='myview';
declare @columnname varchar(100)='overtime_pay';


WITH Details AS
(
    SELECT obj.name AS VIEW_NAME
          ,cols.name AS COLUMN_NAME
          ,vws.VIEW_DEFINITION
    FROM sys.columns AS cols 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects AS obj ON cols.object_id=obj.object_id
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS AS vws ON vws.TABLE_NAME=obj.name 
    WHERE cols.name=@columnname 
     AND  obj.name=@viewname
     AND obj.type_desc='VIEW'
)
,SplittedOnCommaAndFrom AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(VIEW_DEFINITION,',','</x><x>'),'from','</x><x>')+'</x>' AS XML) AsXml 
    FROM Details
)
SELECT VIEW_NAME 
      ,COLUMN_NAME
      ,The.ColumnLine.value('.','varchar(max)') AS COLUMN_DEFINITION
FROM SplittedOnCommaAndFrom 
CROSS APPLY AsXml.nodes('/x[contains(.,sql:column("COLUMN_NAME"))]') AS The(ColumnLine)
```

Comment: This does not work if I have an expression using coalesce(x,y) as the comma in the expression acts as a separator.

Comment: @LLau, well, that's true... One idea could be to find the name of the column with the ordinal index right before the needed column and than parse the characters between these two. This should work, if your columm naming is as unique as `overtime_pay`.Good luck!

Comment: @LLau, Could you solve your problem? Anyway I'd ask you - if this is OK for you - to check this answer as the accepted one. It solves the question you asked... You are right of course, that a computed column with commas would break this approach, but your question  - as it is - is solved, isn't it? Maybe you don't know, that we professionals giving answers here are hungry for reputation points ;-)

Comment: I did solve my problem using parsing of the view_definition, but it was way more complex than what is shown because of complex expressions such as long case statements or inline comments. It also failed if I did not have very precise formatting and it still does not give me 100% of the expressions. With more tweaking I might be able to get it to work in all cases, but I'm only using it to create online documentation of my views, so it was close enough for my needs.

Comment: @LLau, Glad to read, that you could solve (most of) your problem... If you don't mind it would be very kind of you to check this answer as accepted (the check sign below the vote counter) as it was this answer which brought you to the idea of parsing the view_definition and brought you "close enough for your needs".